# reduce (p v ~q) ^ (~p v ~r) using equivalences

Tags: logic

can the law of distribution be used in the following way:

$$(p\vee \neg q)\wedge (\neg p\vee \neg r)$$
$$(p\vee \neg p)\wedge(\neg q\vee \neg r)$$
$$\top\wedge (\neg q \vee \neg r)$$
True

Comment: Apparently not, because the starting formula is not equivalent to FALSE; wit $p$ TRUE and $r$ FALSE the formula is TRUE.

Comment: sorry, I made a typo. have fixed it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula $$(p\vee \neg q)\wedge (\neg p\vee \neg r)$$
is equivalent with
$$(p\vee \neg p)\wedge(\neg q\vee \neg r).$$
However this does not follow from the normal ditributive law, since it only works this way in this particular sentence i.e. when we have $p$ in one side on the conjunction and $\neg p$ in the other side of the conjunction. You can prove that these are equivalent by using a truth table, for instance, or by using formula manipulations such as the distributive law. However it does not follow by only one usage of the distributive law (and not only the distributive law), so I wouldnt say it follows from it.

Also the last conclusion is false: $\top \wedge(\neg q\vee \neg r)$ is equivalent with $\neg q\vee \neg r$, not Truth.